# pip installl tsne doesn't work

Tags: python, pip

I couldn't install tsne package on my Windows machine. I followed the instruction [here](https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne/blob/master/README.md) to install tsne packages for Python. But either `pip install tsne` or `pip install git+https://github.com/danielfrg/tsne.git` works. The error massage is

```
      tsne/bh_sne_src/quadtree.cpp(12) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cblas.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Users\\hzoe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for tsne
      Running setup.py clean for tsne
    Failed to build tsne
    Installing collected packages: tsne
      Running setup.py install for tsne: started
        Running setup.py install for tsne: finished with status 'error'
        Complete output from command C:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\hzoe\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-vicxy7\\tsne\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\hzoe\appdata\local\temp\pip-so57qk-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
        !!!!!!!!!!!!! ['tsne', 'tsne.tests']
        C:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-20.2.2-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dist.py:285: UserWarning: Normalizing 'v0.1.5' to '0.1.5'
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tsne
        copying tsne\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tsne
        copying tsne\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tsne
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tsne\tests
        copying tsne\tests\test_iris.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tsne\tests
        copying tsne\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tsne\tests
        UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tsne/_version.py
        set build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tsne/_version.py to 'v0.1.5'
        running build_ext
        building 'bh_sne' extension
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tsne
        creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tsne\bh_sne_src
        C:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I/usr/local/include -Itsne/bh_sne_src/ -IC:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\PC /Tptsne/bh_sne.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tsne/bh_sne.obj -msse2 -O3 -fPIC -w
        cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
        cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-msse2'
        cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
        cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
        bh_sne.cpp
        c:\users\hzoe\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
        C:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Include\xlocale(342) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
        C:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I/usr/local/include -Itsne/bh_sne_src/ -IC:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\include -IC:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\PC /Tptsne/bh_sne_src/quadtree.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tsne/bh_sne_src/quadtree.obj -msse2 -O3 -fPIC -w
        cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
        cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-msse2'
        cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
        cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
        quadtree.cpp
        tsne/bh_sne_src/quadtree.cpp(12) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cblas.h': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Users\\hzoe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "C:\Users\hzoe\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\hzoe\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-vicxy7\\tsne\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\hzoe\appdata\local\temp\pip-so57qk-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\hzoe\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-vicxy7\tsne\
```

I am using Anaconda for python and I installed Visual C++ compiler for Windows too.

Comment: It looks like your are missing a header file. Is the library that contains clbash.h in your include path?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `conda install -c conda-forge tsne`. Reference from Anaconda [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tsne)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry if you've already tried this, but i couldn't see what you typed into the command prompt to get that error.

If you dont have your path variable set to pip, then type this in (just alter the path if python is in a different directory) and remember its case sensitive!

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install LIBRARY_NAME
```

Comment: I have set up pip path variable. Normally "pip install" would work, but this time when I typed in "pip install tsne", I got this error message

Answer (score 0):

Try importing TSNE from sklearn instead.
Write the below code when importing the libraries at the beginning:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
```