# Tsne: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cblas.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, openblas

I want to install tsne in python.

Running the command:

```
pip install tsne
```

results in the following error:

```
tsne/bh_sne_src/quadtree.cpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include 'cblas.h': No such file or directory
```

I have tried to install openBLAS through by following these instructions https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/wiki/CBLAS-for-Windows.

However, this did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Try adding the openBLAS path to your environment variable

Comment: I have added C:\Users\Nicolai Iversen\OpenBLAS\package\bin. Still does not work..

Comment: Does `…\OpenBLAS\package\bin` contain 'cblas.h'? If not, why did you add it?

Comment: Sorry, meant ...\OpenBLAS\package\include. And this includes cblas.h yes

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643043/pip-installl-tsne-doesnt-work/39643572#39643572